# how to deploy a php website on firebase without using the cloud/database features

Tags: php, html, bash, firebase

I have a directory containing index.php, header.php and footer.php, and I want to deploy this directory in firebase, BUT without using cloud/database features (only firebase deployment). In fact, in my index.php, there are only two PHP tags that are both header and footer inclusions. To do this, my tutor gave me a tip: before writing "firebase deploy", I have to do a PHP command with the > operator. For example, something like "php -S localhost:8000 > ...". Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase won't allow to run PHP Code please check hosting documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/. If you want to run api you can try using nodejs express please refer this doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions.